# Is my phone using both WiFi and 4G?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mobile-network

My Samsung Galaxy S4 (Verizon) running 4.2.2 (with the [VRUAME7](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359090) Build, so root is not an option currently) has both the WiFi and 4G/mobile data symbols in the notification bar, occasionally the mobile data symbol will go away, but it is there more often then not.

[image]

So I have read through [this forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-samsung-galaxy-s4/281533-4g-lte-symbol-wifi-symbol-both-displaying-when-wifi.html) and it says that by turning off the Caller Name ID app that this should remove the mobile data from the notifications. I have done this and it has not removed the symbol.

**Questions**

My phone does not *seem* to be using the mobile data, but I would like to know if it is in fact using the mobile data while connected to WiFi?

Shouldn't/Does the mobile data turn off when connected to WiFi?

If it does not turn off the mobile data, why not and can I fix this with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)? That is a HUGE waste of battery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phone is not using both WiFi and 4G, but the 4G radio stays on and stays in sync with the tower (if you move from a 4G to 3G area while still on WiFi, you'll see the icon change when it recognizes the tower swtich).

On my Droid Bionic (Verizon), I have a Tasker script that turns off Mobile Data when I'm connected to Work or home WiFi networks; my battery life is greatly extended with this setup, and the phone works as I expect (I'm told that MMS messages require the Mobile Data connection, but I rarely receive them, so I can't say if that's true; if so, it may be one reason the radio stays on by default).

Comment: Looks like I'm getting myself Tasker! Thanks! :)

Comment: The things that Tasker can control vary by device and Android version; I don't know if Mobile Data on/off is available on every devices; there's a support forum at http://tasker.dinglisch.net/ if you want to double check.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I had come from iPhone to a Galaxy Nexus for a short period of time and now the S4 for a week, which has a TON for me to learn still!